# Создать функцию, которая будет производить математические операции с введеными пользователем числами

Tags: javascript

- Считать с помощью модального окна браузера два числа.
- Считать с помощью модального окна браузера математическую операцию, которую нужно совершить.
- Создать функцию, в которую передать два значения и операцию.
- Вывести в консоль результат выполнения функции.

То есть как с двумя полученными числами можно совершить операцию, полученную с модального окна.

```js
let numFirst = +prompt("Введите первое число") ||;
let numSecond = +prompt("Введите второе число") ||;
let operator = prompt("Введите знак операции") ||; // любой: +, -, *, /, %

function calcResult (numFirst, numSecond, operator) {
// что в теле?
}
calcResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numFirst = +prompt('Введите первое число');
let numSecond = +prompt('Введите второе число');
let operator = prompt('Введите знак операции'); // любой: +, -, *, /, %

function calcResult(numFirst, numSecond, operator) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '+':
      return numFirst + numSecond;
    case '-':
      return numFirst - numSecond;
    case '*':
      return numFirst * numSecond;
    case '/':
      return numFirst / numSecond;
    case '<':
      return numFirst < numSecond;
    case '>':
      return numFirst > numSecond;
  }
}

alert(calcResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numFirst = +prompt('Введите первое число');
let numSecond = +prompt('Введите второе число');
let operator = prompt('Введите знак операции');

function calcResult(numFirst, numSecond, operator) {
  return eval(`${numFirst}` + operator + `${numSecond}`);
}

alert(calcResult(numFirst, numSecond, operator));
```

Comment: Работает, но тут сразу четыре страшные вещи: prompt, alert, EVAL, eval и Eval, итого - 5 страшных вещей)

Comment: просто ужас получается)